# OOTB Shopping Cart for 2013, product catalog

Tags: 2013, business-data-catalog, catalog, e-commerce

I'm making a product catalog for industrial materials. This catalog will not be for commerce, I just want to allow my users to search and casually add items to a list.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? This is one of the least important features since it can be done with word/notepad/sticky notes so I probably don't want to use anything 3rd party.

I was told making some sort of list is not the best way, so is there even a way? I have no idea what it would take but would a custom web part on the master page be able to accomplish this?